# when using curl to send a PUT request how to pass parameters correctly?

Tags: curl, put

I have a Spring mvc Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "testPut", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public Result<Void> testPut(@RequestParam String foo, @RequestParam String bar) {
    System.out.println(foo + " " + bar) ;
    return Result.success(null);
}
```

when I use curl to test it

```
curl -X PUT  -d "foo=foo&bar=bar" 'http://localhost:8080/testPut'
```

it has below exception

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'foo' is not present
```

When I changed to another way

```
curl -X PUT 'http://localhost:8080/testPut?foo=foo&bar=bar'
```

this time it success. So when if it is a PUT method, you cannot use `-d` to pass parameters?